# 英語が残っている：登録

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

> URL: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/signup
>
> [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

登録したいの時、英語が残っている。

> By registering, you agree to the [privacy policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) and [terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service).

だが、「privacy policy」と「terms of service」が英語版のへリンクされている。日本語版がない。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[unaristさんが適用しました](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40289974?q=by%20registering%20you%20agree)。サイトに適用済みです。

とりあえず、英語のリンク先しかないです（アメリカの会社のため、アメリカ法に基づくため、英語が必要です。日本語版の諸略等を検討しています）。